# Automated explanation - function results - simple attempt

Tags: algorithm

I used to work as an analyst in a financial project where we had functions $f$ determining the price, and sometimes the inputs $x$ jumped in such a way to produce anomalous results.
We had to report an explanation, and I wish to automate the process.
It's not properly a question of AI, more of information science.
The idea is that once, for a generic non-linear $f$, you can determine the ranking of relevance of $x_i$ in explaining the result, you can generate a full explanation by:

1. decompose $f$ as a composition of $f_j$, which are intermediate results with a definite meaning in the application domain (in this case, finance)
2. apply the algorithm using the $f_j$ instead of $x_i$, and then iterate it to explain the $f_j$ in terms of $x_i$

The relevance is quantified by the information gain of each variable. This will be explained for an application in ranking the $x_i$ directly.
We assume to start on a uniform distribution on the $x$ domain, calculate the derived probability density function for $f$, and the information entropy of $f$.
Then we fix the $x_i$ one at a time, for each calculate the new p.d.f. of $f$ conditioned on that $x_i$ and the (lower) information entropy of $f$. The information gain is $IG(x_i)$.
Choose as the first conditioning the $i$ with the largest information gain, then condition of the remaining $i$ with a decreasing order of $IG_i$.
So we could start for example , with $(x_1,x_2,x_3)$, to condition first on $x_2$, then on $(x_2,x_3)$, and then on $(x_2,x_3,x_1)$, getting the percentage contributions as:
$\frac{IG_i}{H_y}$. The successive terms $IG_i$ add up always to the total entropy $H_y$, since conditioning on all variables gives a point and zero entropy.

Any opinion on how to improve this "automated function explanation" is welcome